# How to configure static assets for server build in angular universal app?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Is it possible to include static assets in server build? An official documentation https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration says nothing about it.

I want to deploy my Angular Universal app on iis and I need a web.config file for that. But when I include assets array with this file into server configuration in angular.json, build crashes with an error: `Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(assets).`

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "MyApp": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "..."
        "build": {
          ...
        },
        "server": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              "src/web.config"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have to add the web.config file into assets in 'build' section. But I don't like it because I don't want this file in browser build.

Comment: Looks like you just defined the assets in the wrong place. I think it should be under `build/options`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle, I keep it in assets under `build/options` now just because I have not found any better solution. But web.config relates only to server build, and I would prefer not to include it to browser build.

Comment: @lonelLupu, unfortunately no, I didn't. I include my server assets to a browser build and then move them to the correct folder.